# why composition series for groups are of finite length?

Tags: group-theory

*def :* a composition series of a group **G** is a subnormal series of **finite length**

$$ 1 \vartriangleleft H_1 \vartriangleleft H_2 \vartriangleleft \cdot   \cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot \vartriangleleft H_n = G $$

with strict inclusions, such that each $H_i$ is a maximal strict normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}$ .

*question :* can there be an subnormal series of **infinite length** with strict inclusions such that for all $i$ , $H_i$ is a maximal strict normal subgroup of $H_{i+1}$.Is this even true for **uncountable** indexed chain of subgroups.Why the finiteness is important in the def ?

Comment: See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2725318/11619) for some discussion. Hmm. Not sure it answers your question...

Answer (score 2):

One reason for finiteness is that in all composition series we absolutely want [Jordan-Hölder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_series#Uniqueness:_Jordan%E2%80%93H%C3%B6lder_theorem) to hold.

That may become a bit problematic if we allow infinite series. If we look at countable series $$1\lhd \cdots \lhd H_{n}\lhd H_{n-1}\lhd\cdots\lhd H_1\lhd G$$
a natural "terminating condition" is to insists that
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty H_i=\{1\}.
$$
But if only require this we lose Jordan-Hölder. This can be seen already with the infinite cyclic group $\Bbb{Z}$.

We get one sequence of maximal normal subgroups by declaring $H_n=2^n\Bbb{Z}$. In this case all the composition factors are $H_n/H_{n+1}\simeq C_2$. On the other hand, if $2=p_1<p_2<p_3<\cdots$ are all the prime numbers listed in sequence, and we declare
$$H'_k=(p_1p_2\cdots p_k)\Bbb{Z},$$
then we get a different set of composition factors as this time
$$
H'_{k-1}/H'_{k}\simeq C_{p_k}.
$$
Observe that, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, both "normal series" here satisfy the terminating condition
$$
\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty H_i=\{0\}=\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty H'_i,
$$
and in both cases all the quotients were simple.

---

I'm sure more can be said, but I am not the right person to try. Leaving this as an example and/or the first potential problem that occurred to me.